# Kohana 3.1: How to work with many databases?

Tags: php, database, kohana

In my project each user has own database where **dbname = username**. So, I can't to list all DB in my config `database.php` file.
How I can set DB name in controller?
I'm trying with:
`$config = Kohana::config('database.default');

        $config['connection']['database'] = Session::instance()->get('login');

        Database::instance('custom', $config);

        Database::$default = 'custom';`

And this is doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can run this piece of code:

```
Database::instance ($name, array (
    'type'       => '<type>',
    'connection' => array(
      'hostname'   => '<host>',
      'username'   => '<user>',
      'password'   => '<pass>',
      'persistent' => FALSE,
      'database'   => '<db>',
      ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'charset'      => 'utf8',
    'caching'      => FALSE,
    'profiling'    => TRUE,
));
```

Use the same parameters as you would use in *config/database.php*.

If you don't need to use a `'default'` database for any additional processing, you can set `$name = 'default';` and run everything as usual.